# Appium checking if element is displayed

Tags: appium

I'm using Appium for Android

the following works for clicking on the element

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.app.android:id/prelogin_signup']")).click();
```

But I am trying to check if an element is on the screen and I tried the following

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.app.android:id/prelogin_signup']")).isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("FOUND");
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT FOUND!");
}
```

but it returns an Exception saying

```
INFO: HTTP Status: '405' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented
```

How can I check to see if an element is on the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this, hope it helps

//If the element found, do as you want

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.app.android:id/prelogin_signup']")).size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("FOUND");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND!");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can surround your code with try catch block.

```
public boolean isElementDisplayed(){
    try{
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.app.android:id/prelogin_signup']")).isDisplayed();

    }catch(Exception e){
        //System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

you can also make the **generic function** to check if element is displayed.

```
public boolean isElementDisplayed(MobileElement element){
    try{
        return element.isDisplayed();

    }catch(Exception e){
        //System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the original poster's example locator in your example.  You should also consider that while there should be a try/catch block, you're not checking for specific exceptions, so any exception might be misleading and cause debugging problems under certain circumstances, especially since your example doesn't show any exception handling at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try isDisplayed().

```
 if (demoPage.proceedButton().isDisplayed() == true) {
            System.out.println("BUTTON FOUND*****");
            TestUtil.click(cartPage.proceedButton(), 10);
        } else {
            System.out.println("PROCEED BUTTON NOT FOUND!*********");
        }
```

Note - I am using Page Factory model. Hence, demoPage.proceedButton() is used, you may use your locator in place of this declaration.